# image map does not work in google chrome

Tags: image, dictionary, imagemap

Can any one tell me where the error is in this html coding?

https://newmedia.leeds.ac.uk/ug10/cs10jy/portfolio/studenthands/imagemap.html

I have wrote this code but I cant seem to see where i'm going wrong after looking online and following tutorials...

```
<img src ="images/socialnetwork.png"
width="220" border="0"
usemap ="#socialmap" />

<map id ="socialmap"
name="socialmap">
<area shape ="poly" coords ="77,83,163,127"
 href ="https://www.facebook.com/StudentHands" target="_blank" />
<area shape ="poly" coords ="1,105,75,153"
href ="https://twitter.com/StudentHands" target="_blank" />
</map>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Change the id attribute of map tag with **name** attribute, it will work

Answer (score 1):

```
<area shape ="poly" coords ="77,83,163,127"
 href ="https://www.facebook.com/StudentHands" target="_blank" />
```

the coordinates doesnt form a polygon it can just make a line.
the coords are taken as "x1,y1,x2,y2,......xn,yn" where n>=3

Comment: Or it should be `shape="rect"`, maybe

Answer (score 1):

Remove the linebreaks and the spaces between attribute and = in the code for the map. That should help.

try this

```
<img src="images/socialnetwork.png" width="220" border="0" usemap="#socialmap" />

<map id="socialmap" name="socialmap">
<area shape ="poly" coords ="77,83,163,127" href ="https://www.facebook.com/StudentHands" target="_blank" />
<area shape ="poly" coords ="1,105,75,153" href ="https://twitter.com/StudentHands" target="_blank" />
</map>
```